# what does these three lines of code do when initializing an express app in Node.js with socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

Can anyone explain these three lines of code?

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

The first line of code, from what i understand, is for initializing express.js, but what is the empty parentheses for?

The second line of code is for initializing http server, but what is the purpose of `.createServer(app)`? Why does it accept `app` as a parameter?

The third line is for initializing socket.io, but what is the purpose for the second parentheses `(http)`. Why does it accept `http` as a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var app = require('express')();` is equivalent to

```
var Express = require('express') // load express node module
var app = Express() // create Express server instance
```

Similarly, `var http = require('http').createServer(app);` equals to

```
var http = require('http') // loads http module
var serverOnSomePort = http.createServer(app) // create responding to user requests Express server
```

And finally, `var io = require('socket.io')(http);`

```
var socketio = require('socket.io') // loading socket.io npm module
var io = socketio(serverOnSomePort) // connects socket to running server
```